# Порефакторить скрипт календаря

Tags: jquery, события, инспекция-кода, calendar

Есть календарь событий (неделя) формируется динамически, структура: days > day(7) > cell(24) > event-item (добавляются динамически их может быть разное количество). Нужно с помощью jQuery each пройтись по всем дням недели и найти все event-item, которые начинаются в одно и тоже время (день и время). Добавить им класс и с помощью стилей добавить свойства left и right которые динамически рассчитываются.

Вышло вот так ну и нужно наверняка отрефакторить код:

```js
$('.week-view .hour-grid .days').each(function() {
  const cell = $(this).find('.cell');

  for (let i = 0; i < cell.length; i++) {
    const eventsList = cell[i];
    const events = eventsList.children.length;

    if (events > 1) {
      for (const event of eventsList.children) {
        event.classList.add('overlap');
      }
      console.log(events);
      console.log(eventsList);
      for (let y = 0; y < events; y++) {
        let left = 100 / events * y + '%';
        let right = 100 - 100 / events * (y + 1) + '%';
        console.log(left);
        console.log(right);
        $('.event-item.overlap').eq(y).css({
          'left': left,
          'right': right
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="days">
  <div class="day">
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 00:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 01:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 02:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 03:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 04:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 05:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 06:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 07:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 08:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 09:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 10:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 11:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 12:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 13:00"></div>
    <div class="event-item" style="border-color: #89D260; top: 0.0px; height: 100.0px; left: 0px; right: 0px"></div>
    <div class="event-item" style="border-color: #89D260; top: 0.0px; height: 100.0px; left: 0px; right: 0px"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 13:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 14:00">
      <div class="event-item" style="border-color: #89D260; top: 0.0px; height: 100.0px; left: 0px; right: 0px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 15:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 16:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 17:00">
      <div class="event-item" style="border-color: #89D260; top: 0.0px; height: 100.0px; left: 0px; right: 0px"></div>
      <div class="event-item" style="border-color: #89D260; top: 0.0px; height: 100.0px; left: 0px; right: 0px"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 18:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 19:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 20:00"></div>
    <div class="cell" data-date="2020-08-29" data-time-start="August 29, 2020 21:00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
  <div class="day">.....</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sergsagan/Lurydtaf/

Comment: Нужен практический совет, помощь - я понимаю что скрипт далеко не оптимальный и хотел бы его оптимизировать

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста описание метки "инспекция-кода" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info), а также, попробуйте дать вопросу более толковое название.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У любого рефакторинга должна быть цель. Что вы хотите получить в итоге? Более гибкий и легко поддерживаемый код? Более компактый и простой код? Код, который удивит вашего оппонента на собеседовании?

Если вы хотите в будущем дорабатывать этот календарь, то вам следовало бы интегрировать своё решение в тот динамический календарь (судя по коду его генерирует js), который уже есть. Или по крайней мере использовать его методы для доступа к событиям. Например можно написать какой-нибудь декоратор для событий, который изменит их отображение. Это ООП-путь.

Если же вы хотите именно хакнуть календарь, выполнив процедуру, которая изменит его DOM снаружи, то вам следует иметь ввиду вот что.

Во-первых, какое-нибудь событие (я говорю про js-события) в календаре может вызвать рендринг его дней и ячеек, и тогда ваши стили может просото затереть и вы получите трудноуловимый баг с прыгающими собыиями.

Во-вторых, то, что вы пытаетесь сделать через left/rigth можно сделать через flex.

Если класс `overlap` действительно нужно добавить, то сделать это можно так:

```
$('.week-view .hour-grid .days .cell').each(function() {
    var $events = $(this).children();
    if ($events.length > 1) { // события в одной ячейке происходят в одно и то же время
        $events.addClass('overlap');
    }
});
```

Для размещения событий в ячейке друг за другом можно написать такой стиль:

```
.week-view .hour-grid .days .cell {
    display: flex;
}
.week-view .hour-grid .days .cell > * {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Возможно некотрые предусловия, о котрых я не догадываюсь, не позволят сделать это именно так. Но как идея, думаю, вам пригодится.

Comment: Спасибо Богдан: но смотрите что я хотел бы получить - код должен быть only jquery (у меня же смесь), кроме того более оптимизирован (возможно с меньшей долей вложености), сделать нужно только через left и right (так заложена логика на ruby on rails), календарь хакать мне не нужно -он у нас самописный и работает давно, просто логику позиционирование event-ов перенесли на frontend и моя задача красиво эти ивенты разместить, когда их больше одного) Что вы хотите получить в итоге? - более компактый и простой код на jquery

Comment: судя по коду его генерирует js - нет календарь генерируется на ruby on rails, а позиционирование событий выноситься на фронтенд

Comment: Ваше решение принимаю как верный ответ ибо код сократился, работает ну и Вы меня натолкнули на мысли:) Спасибо.